# Difference between Icon properties in info.plist?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm working on an iPhone app and I'm not sure which plist property to use out of the following:

[image: xcode plist editor]

Could anyone shed some light on what each of them do and the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple requires that you include an icon that measures 57x57 pixels.  If you are just going to use that image, then you put it under the **Icon File** property.

However, Apple recommends that you include images of different sizes for different purposes, such as for the retina display, the ipad, and the search bar.  If you are going to include multiple images, which will make your app look better, especially the retina one, then you include all of those images in the **Icon Files** property.  Do note that you do not need the Icon File property if you are using the Icon Files property.

I am still developing for IOS 4 so I do not know about the **Icon Files (IOS 5)** property but I would assume that there are new places where your icon might pop up in IOS 5 where it will not pop up in older IOS versions.  You would place those images under that property.

Hope that helps.